# In javascript How can I check upload file size

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have input with id case_attachment and I have tried get file size like this

```
($('#case_attachment'))[0].files[0].size
```

but it does not work on IE9

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support this feature :(

I had found a great plugin for file upload [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

or you better use an ActiveX control to perform this action

```
function getSize()
{
 var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
 var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
 var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
 var size = thefile.size;
 alert(size + " bytes");
}
```

source: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196859-File-Upload-Field-IE-Safari-Opera-fileInput-error.&s=b124834725ae363759158268d91ac32c

Comment: I have tried like this but it give an error
"Automation server can't create object"

Comment: The error "Automation Server Can't Create Object" means that your browser's security settings are too low for the ActiveX control to run. You have to move your page into the trusted sites list and lower the ActiveX settings so it can run.